# Built in function in numpy to interpret an Integer as a numpy array with index = integer value set

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to numpy and I am trying to avoid for-loops. My requirement is as below:

```
Input - decimal value (ex. 3)
Output - Binary numpy array ( = 00000 01000)
```

Another example :

```
Input = 6
Output = 00010 00000
```

Note: I do not want the binary representation of 3. I only need the index value of array = integer to be set.

Is there any standard library function in numpy? Something analogous to get_dummies function in pandas module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead. This doesn't use any for loops and if you add some sanity checks it should work fine.

```
def oneOfK(label):
    rows = label.shape[0];
    rowsIndex=np.arange(rows,dtype="int")
    oneKLabel = np.zeros((rows,10))
    #oneKLabel = np.zeros((rows,np.max(label)+1))
    oneKLabel[rowsIndex,label.astype(int)]=1
    return oneKLabel
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a standard function that does something like:

```
import numpy as np

def foo(d, len=10):
    a = np.zeros(len)
    a[len-d-1] = 1
    return a

print foo(3)  # [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
print foo(6)  # [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

This is more of a comment with code than an answer.  Just trying to be clear about what you're looking for, because I'm not sure this function exists as you specify.

Comment: If you do `np.zeros(len, dtype='bool')`, this will give a boolean array.